# android listview with radio button not displaying the content in simple list item single choice

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

i am trying to show a list view with radio button of single choice mode.

Following is my bit of code

```
ListView l1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

for(int i = 0; i <firstlist.size(); i++)
        {           
            f = firstlist.get(i);
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
            map.put("fname", f);
            listItem1.add(map);
        }
        SimpleAdapter listItemAdapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(this,listItem1,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,new String[] {"fname"}, new int[] {R.id.fname});   
        l1.setAdapter(listItemAdapter1);
        l1.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(l1);
            }
        }, 400);
        l1.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        l1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Everything is working fine but the problem is my background color of the layout is white and i have set my text in listview color to be as black, but the text in list view is not viewable.

When i gave a long press the list color gets highlighted and then only the text appears. When i release it disappears.

How to change the selected list radio button color to be as red, is it possible

How to make the text get viewable.

Answer (score 0):

Once try set the listview property cacheColorHint to Transparent, It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array adapter by which you can add any theme but with simple list with choice mode the text color can't be changed 
but problem with array adapter is that as you scroll your check boxes get unchecked

so to get resolved create an xml file in your layout folder
style_list.xml
paste this code in that

```
  <CheckBox xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
       android:id="@android:id/text2" 
       android:paddingTop="10dip"
       android:paddingLeft="25dip"
       android:paddingBottom="10dip"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:textSize="15dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:background="#ffffffff"
       android:textColor="#000000"/>

and then change your adapter line code as 

 SimpleAdapter listItemAdapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(this,listItem1,R.layout.style_list,new String[] {"fname"}, new int[] {R.id.fname});
```

and replace list view xml with this

```
 <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="200dip"
             android:id="@+id/your_order_list"
             android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
             android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: ur idea is good but still same problem continues and i want to show a radio button or some thing just like that....

Comment: oh i have forgot just change in xml file TextView tag to CheckBox and android:background="#ffffffff" this will give a sure help

Comment: use this
  <CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text2" 
     android:paddingTop="10dip"
     android:paddingLeft="25dip"
     android:paddingBottom="10dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:textSize="15dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:background="#ffffffff"
     android:textColor="#000000"/>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8384/discussion-between-vipin-and-siva-k)